# VSCode : How to get remote-ssh output by api?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote-ssh

I want to get the output content of remote-ssh and analyze these logs in my extension.
I tried this method

```
        let response = vscode.commands.executeCommand('opensshremotes.showLog');
        console.log(response)
```

But the response is not the log content. Is there any method else?

[remote ssh output content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Dw0.png)